# SQL counting attributes of an item

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL but learning more every day!
These are columns in the same table
I am having trouble with this particular logic:

```
  |Products|Ingredients|
      cake       milk
      cookie     eggs
      cake       eggs
      brownie    sugar
      cake       sugar
      cookie     sugar
      brownie    eggs
      cake       milk
      cookie     sugar
      brownie    sugar
```

I am looking to count how many times each ingredient is associated with each product

```
cake     milk  2
         eggs  1
         sugar 1
brownie  sugar 2
         eggs  1
cookie   eggs  1
         sugar 2
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  Can you tell me if `Products` and `Ingredients` are different `tables` or different `columns` within the same `table`?  The correct answer will depend on this.  (Maybe update your question?)

Comment: Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it. It is a very simple `group by`. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list all column which you want to group by in the GROUP BY clause, and you apply the aggregate function (COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc.) to the column you want as result in the SELECT clause:

```
   SELECT Products,
          Ingredients,
          COUNT(Ingredients) AS CountOfIngredients
     FROM Table1
 GROUP BY Products,
          Ingredients
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e6e85/6/0)

Comment: I was trying to group multiple with "AND" instead of ","
it feels bad to make such a noobish mistake but this has taught me I need more multiple grouping practice
thank you for your speedy answer

Answer (score 0):

Using count aggregate would provide the count of the Ingredients. And group the required Columns using  Group by

Try out the below Query :

SELECT product ,Ingredient ,count(Ingredient) FROM table_name
GROUP BY product,Ingredient